# Xamarin android native library invoker

Tags: android, xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms

How can I use/get instance of IPaymentRequestInvoker of an android .aar module in Xamarin form/android.

Android binding library generated following class(Decompiled):
It contains an interface and an internal class.

```
 namespace IR.Sep.Paymentservices.Req
  {
  [Register("ir/sep/paymentservices/req/IPaymentRequest", "", "IR.Sep.Paymentservices.Req.IPaymentRequestInvoker")]
  public interface IPaymentRequest : IInterface, IJavaObject, IDisposable
  {
    [Register("startPaymentProcess", "(Landroid/os/Bundle;Lir/sep/paymentservices/res/IPaymentResponseHandler;)V", "GetStartPaymentProcess_Landroid_os_Bundle_Lir_sep_paymentservices_res_IPaymentResponseHandler_Handler:IR.Sep.Paymentservices.Req.IPaymentRequestInvoker, AndroidSamanPay")]
    void StartPaymentProcess(Bundle p0, IPaymentResponseHandler p1);
  }
}
```

internal class:

```
    [global::Android.Runtime.Register ("ir/sep/paymentservices/req/IPaymentRequest", DoNotGenerateAcw=true)]
internal class IPaymentRequestInvoker : global::Java.Lang.Object, IPaymentRequest {

// code ...
    static IntPtr java_class_ref = JNIEnv.FindClass ("ir/sep/paymentservices/req/IPaymentRequest");
     public IPaymentRequestInvoker (IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base (Validate (handle), transfer)
    {
        IntPtr local_ref = JNIEnv.GetObjectClass (((global::Java.Lang.Object) this).Handle);
        this.class_ref = JNIEnv.NewGlobalRef (local_ref);
        JNIEnv.DeleteLocalRef (local_ref);
    }

// code ...
```

This module is a bank gateway and run an activity for payment process.
Is there any way to call StartPaymentProcess method?

Comment: Hi, have you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar#accessing-aar-types)?

Comment: Any luck on this? im in a similar situation. My library has a Factory class to create the class i need to use, but it returns an interface type. When i look into the .aar library using JD-GUI, i can see the classes that implement the interface, but they have no access modifier of any type (public, private, protected, static, etc.)